# Reducing APK size by removing mdpi

Tags: android

I am trying to reduce my apk size. Currently it is 7 Mb after using Proguard. It's a very huge size for a small app. So can I remove mdpi and xxhdpi images from /drawable?

Comment: add inside build.gradle(app) buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: Instead of using all images with different resolutions.You can use [Vector asset](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) for images if it's possbile.

Comment: I have ued proguard but not that much reduction of size of apk ,it reduced  from 7.9 to 7.2 mb

Answer (score 3):

Use folllowing property of proguard
**minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true**

You can reduce PNG file sizes without losing image quality using tools like pngcrush, pngquant, or zopflipng. All of these tools can reduce PNG file size while preserving image quality.

There are also more tricks and methods For More info in Details [Read the Official Documentation of Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html)

Comment: it is not good approach to delete mdpi or xhxhdpi . first analysis that which part of app is responsible size (For example external libraries or  PNG's )

Comment: How can i check which part of apk is reasonable for size(res/externallib),please help me.I am using android studio 1.3 i know its too old.but please help me to check which part is contributing more sie.

Comment: check your resource like size of images

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Reduce apk size|Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html)

> If you know that only a small percentage of your users have devices with specific densities, consider whether you need to bundle those densities into your app. If you don't include resources for a specific screen density, Android automatically scales existing resources originally designed for other screen densities.

You can remove mdpi drawables if you are sure enough that most of your user don't use devices which supports mdpi drawables.

In case of xxhdpi the page [Reduce apk size|Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html) suggests

> We recommend that every app include at least an xxhdpi image variant.

So you should keep xxhdpi according to this.

Comment: you are giving the same reference url as i give in my answer

Comment: Actually I was typing my answer and meanwhile you might have posted your answer so I wasn't aware about your answer. I gave my answer.

Comment: I have 1 doubt during apk creation all the drawable (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi) will packed into dex file.or only some drawable.